# Не могу сообразить, как сменить путь в настройках кода к базе данных фотографий в Google Colab?

Tags: pycharm, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, directory

Портировал код из PyCharm в Google Colab и не пойму,как прописать путь правильно в Colab

Изначально путь прописан вот так

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-705c8eed7429> in <module>()
     25 
     26 directory = R'/home/abbat108/photo/'
---> 27 dir_list: list[str] = os.listdir(directory)
     28 agreements = []  # List with pictures names
     29 for filename in dir_list:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/abbat108/photo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Там проще прописывать относительный путь, а сами файлы копировать с гита для каждой сессии, тогда получается, вы запускаете команду:
!git clone http://github.com/username/project.git

А дальше у вас появляется папка project, которую вы и указываете как путь